# How to get to this path /etc/hadoop/conf on EMR cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

I am new to EMR and Spark. I am going through this steps mentioned here https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-submit-spark-job-remote-cluster/ . In step#5 it says **Copy all files in /etc/hadoop/conf on the remote Amazon EMR cluster.**. 
want to know how to get those files from /etc/hadoop/conf.

If my understanding is wrong please correct me. Thanks and appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access to the instance of EMR through *ssh*, enter the folder /etc/hadoop/conf and copy all the files into local or somewhere. You can find the IP address of EMR instances from the EMR console page, hardware tab.

You should set the access key-pair during the creation of a remote EMR cluster. It is the same as the EC2 key pair.